# How to change string class name in middle of code?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-listview

I'm making an Android app, and it's basically a tour guide app. I have it where the user can click the city name on the main page, and they will be shown a list for that city. From there, they can get whatever info needed.
Below is the list Java code.

```
public class Alantic extends ListActivity{
String classes[] = { "City history", "Fort Macon", "example2", "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Alantic.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String abc = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.techreviewsandhelp.carteretcountyhistoryguide." + abc);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent("Alantic.this, ourClass");
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The problem I'm running into is the string names. Obviously anyone can see something like "City history" and know what they will get. But, you can't put spaces in XML names and you can't reuse the name. I'm trying to figure out how to keep it where the user can see something like City history, but the software change that to what's needed in the back end.

Is this possible. If so, how?

Comment: Is there a way to do some if statement? Like if string is "City history" change to "beachcity", if "Fort Macon" change to "fortmacon"

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 public class Testing {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String classes[] = { "City history", "example1", "example2",
            "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6" };
    String abc = classes[0].replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println(abc);
}
}
```

In case of City History just name the class to CityHistory.java.

Comment: When I added that I got an error followed by another. The first error was "The method replaceAll(string,String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String)" this basically adds abc in the ("",""). When it puts abc in, the new error says "The local variable abc may not have been initialized."

Comment: @user280655 I tried my previous code is working as expected. To ensure that I tried it again and it was successful again. Please check your code and resolve the errors.

Comment: @user280655 The first error message makes it look like you put _one_ parameter in the `replaceAll` call inside the parentheses, instead of two.  The code in the answer shows two strings inside parentheses.  Are you sure you typed it in correctly?

Comment: Ya, I didn't know I needed to keep both.

So basically, I need to add ("","") for each string. For example, ("City history","beachcity")("example1","bla")

Comment: It isn't working. I'm getting a Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor. This is with doing the following, ("City history", "beachcity"), ("Fort Macon","fortmacon");